# Flex, FileReferences upload() error in firefox

Tags: apache-flex, firefox, upload, filereference

swf file in https zone, upload script in http zone.
File upload fine in ie, and not work on firefox, opera.

this code:

```
request.url = this.main.serverHostUpload + "/upload_web.php";

request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + UploadPostHelper.getBoundary();

request.data = new URLVariables();
request.data.dst_file = fileDstName;

request.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader( 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache' ) );

var fr:FileReference = this.main.photos[this.iLoadPh].fr;
fr.cancel();

fr.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA,createOrderStep6Res);
fr.upload(request,"file");
```

Comment: _how_ they don't work actually? error?

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems and sometimes it is the quality of the cert if you are posting over https.  You also should make sure that fileference is calling a URL with the actual port number (443 for https).

I have also seen fire reference reconnect in browsers other than IE.  You can spot this using something like Tamper Data for Firefox or Fiddler to get a NIC-level view of it.

Comment: I discovered the fundamental problem was that FileReference was using the WinInit process (same as MSIE), but discarding session information that was registered by FireFox and used for non-FileReference requests.  The server sees your FileReference request as a totally different user agent.